# html.resolveurl not hitting controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I am working on ASP .NET MVC Application. I have an ascx page which has the following line in it.

```html
<embed id="pdfDoc"
       style="width: 775px; height: 970px"
       src="<%=  Html.ResolveUrl("~/ControllerName/GeneratePDF")%>"
       type="application/pdf" />
```

When this ascx is rendered, this action GeneratePDF is supposed to be called. I have a break point in the  controller, but its not hitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would use the mvc routing function `Url.Action()`:

```
Url.Action("GeneratePDF","ControllerName")
```

The `Html.ResolveUrl()` function is fine for resolving relative paths, however, it does not take into consideration routing.